# LiDAR derived streams - map scale

Tags: dem, lidar, scale, hydrology, stream

Historically, streams were defined by the map scale. For example, for a map with a scale of 1:24,000 would mean that the streams identified on that map would be 1:24,000 streams.

With streams that are identified from LiDAR with a nominal pulse spacing (NPS) of 0.35 meters, resulting in a 1-ft DEM, what would be the equivalent scale of this?

Are there any resources that anyone can share that discusses the comparability? Has anyone tackled this issue?